# why shifting operation by 1 Not 0?

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement simple C language code as i'm a beginner.
I'm using the `OR` operation for the first time on a buffer 8 bit size then applying shift right operation.
I found something strange that sometimes the shifting I'd add by 1 not 0 & some cases is added by 0 correctly.

My code:

```
char buffer[0]={0x7e};  
int bitsetcounter; 
int bitCounter; 
int s=1;

int main () {
    if (s=1) {
        buffer[0]=buffer[0]|0x80;
        bitsetcounter++;
        bitCounter++;
    }

    buffer[0] >>=1;
    printf("the buffer is %x",buffer[0]& 0xff);
}
```

The output >> the buffer is ff.
Here why the output like that ? i should have 7F not ff in case i shifting by add 0 value ?

Comment: You should probably learn the difference between assignment `=` and comparison for equality `==`.

Comment: `char` is probably signed on your platform, so you're probably right-shifting a negative number (which isn't allowed).

Comment: ohhh i got it thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the

```
char buffer[0]={0x7e};
```

with the

```
unsigned char buffer[0]={0x7e};
```

But still >> operator is platform dependent